# Confusion regarding Conditional Random Fields

Tags: computer-vision, crf

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbnTx.png

I am trying to label objects in am image using Conditional Random Fields. But I am stuck understanding this formula.
Can anyone tell me the meaning the terms of the formula and how to calculate them.
I am using MS-COCO data set which has labelled images i.e I have segmented images.

Here Z(.)= partition function and P(ci | Sj)= Probability that Sj segment of Image I belongs to class ci and q= no of pairwise spatial relations.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact the the conditional probability distribution of the labeling `c={c1,c2,...,ck}` for the image segments, given the segments features `S={S1,S2,...,Sk}`. `p(ci|Si)` is the probability of assigning class label `ci` to segment `i`, which can be computed using various classifiers like logistic regression, neural network, or SVM. The term `B` presents the aggregate pairwise function that determines how likely it is for each adjacent pair of `{i,j}` to take labels `{ci,cj}`. This term can be reallized by computing the co-occurrence statistics of different class pairs in the dataset, which is described in detail in this paper:
**[Object Categorization using Co-Occurrence, Location and Appearance](http://vision.cornell.edu/se3/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/galleguillos_cvpr08.pdf)**